# Shogi Notation explained

Tags: shogi

I tried to find a shogi game that I could follow on my shogi board. however I am having difficulty following the notation. For example I found http://www2.teu.ac.jp/gamelab/SHOGI/amaryu93.html via google. The game starts with

```
1.P7f P8d 
2.S6h P3d
3.S7g ..
```

Now I think that Move number 1 should move a pawn, however on the board http://www.shogi.net/rjhare/pieces/start.gif 7 f does not hold a pawn. Also, moving it to 8d would mean that it had to move diagnoally, which does not make much sense. So what I came up with is that it could mean that it was the target of a pawn move, which would mean that black moved the pawn from 7g to 7f and white from 8c to 8d. is this the right interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shogi Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi#Notation) notes which piece is moving, and where they are moving to. So P7f means that a Pawn is moving to square 7f. If there is ambiguity as to which piece is moving then the starting location is added to the front (ex. G6i-5h when there is more than one Gold piece that can move to the 5h square)